# Select a div using tab key and add event on enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I using tab key selection for select a div .when I select that div using tab key and on click enter I want to execute a function .
the code I am using is given below:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#tree', function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {debugger
                if($(".userLi").is( ":focus" )){
                    debugger
                } 
        }
    });
```

but this focus div is not getting for me. is thare any idea to do this ?

Comment: If you want to allow the tab key to focus on a div element you'll need to add a `tabindex` attribute to it. Note that this may not work in all browsers though

Comment: no, it is focusing. how can I get the focused div id when I click enter key?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow the tab key to focus on a div element you'll need to add a `tabindex` attribute to it. Note that this may not work in older browsers.

From there you can use the `target` property of the event passed to the handler function to reference the individual `div` which raised the event. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#tree', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13)
    showTextInConsole($(e.target).text());
});

function showTextInConsole(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree">
  <div tabindex="1">One</div>
  <div tabindex="2">Two</div>
  <div tabindex="3">Three</div>
  <div tabindex="4">Four</div>
  <div tabindex="5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `(".userLi:focus")` to get the focused `.userLi` element. The code `$(".userLi").is( ":focus" )` will return you the boolean value if the element is focused or not. But not the actual element that is focused.

Comment: $(".userLi:focus") .length is getting as zero